# Laravel Mail Sending

Tags: php, angularjs, email, laravel

I want to change the email sender's address when I send the mail in my application. The new email address is the address of the login user,I don't want the address from the configuration file (mail.php).

How can I change it? I cannot find any relation online solution. Please help !

This is my mail.php file:

```
array(

  'driver'       => 'smtp',

  'host'      => 'smtp.gmail.com',

  'port'      => 465,

  'from'      => array('address' => "test@gmail.com", 'name' => "Jasmin"),

  'encryption'    => 'ssl',

  'username'  => "jasmin.test12@gmail.com",

  'password'  => "*********",

  'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

  'pretend' => false,

);
```

And this is in my controller:

```
Mail::send('view.view1', $data, function($message)  use ($data)
{
        $message->from($data['from'], 'Hello world!');
        $message->to($data['to'])->subject($data['object']);
});
```

When I run, mail is always sent from : "jasmin.test12@gmail.com" which is the username in the cofiguration file (mail.php). 
The email address of the sender should be from $data['from'] where I defined here :

```
$message->from($data['from'], 'Hello world!');
```

Note**: All elements in the array of $data is fine.

I use gmail as smtp service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to config with your own mail server then try to set difference sender email address to test send an email. It may work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a laravel issue, google doesn't send your E-Mail with a different email address unless you have verified the sender email address.

You can read [**here**](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en) how to set up your email account for sending with google.

Or, do yourself a favour and use a smtp provider with less restrictions, such as [**mandrill**](https://mandrill.com/).
Mandrill is fully supported by laravel and let's you send 12.000 emails per month for free.